# Flowable Multi Instance Call Activity - Output Parameters

Tags: java, bpmn, flowable

Having the following definition in my BPMN model (Flowable Engine):

```
<callActivity id="111-example-111" name="CALLING_SUBPROCESS_MULTIINSTANCE" calledElement="SOME_SUBPROCESS" flowable:calledElementType="key" flowable:fallbackToDefaultTenant="false">
<extensionElement>
    <flowable:in source="INPUT_VAR" target="SUB_INPUT_VAR"></flowable:in>
    <flowable:out source="SUB_OUTPUT_VAR" target="OUTPUT_VAR"></flowable:out>
</extensionElement>
<multiInstanceLoopCharacteristics isSequential="true" flowable:collection="SOME_COLLECTION" flowable:elementVariable="SOME_ELEMENT"></multiInstanceLoopCharacteristics>
```

call activity is correctly processed but I am unable to pass the output variable `SUB_OUTPUT_VAR` to the parent process. I tried some other syntax like:

```
<flowable:out source="SUB_OUTPUT_VAR" target="OUTPUT_VAR_${loopCounter}"></flowable:out>
```

because each loop can produce `SUB_OUTPUT_VAR` and I want to pass all of them to the parent process. But it didn't help.

Is there any way to do it using Flowable BPMN Engine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Collecting variables from a multi instance is a problem that has been in Flowable (and other similar engines for a while).

Your proposed solution with

```
<flowable:out source="SUB_OUTPUT_VAR" target="OUTPUT_VAR_${loopCounter}"></flowable:out>
```

However, in the upcoming 6.7.0 release. There will be a better solution for this. You would be able to use Variable Aggregations.

e.g.

You would be able to define the output as

```
<flowable:out source="SUB_OUTPUT_VAR" target="OUTPUT_VAR"></flowable:out>
```

and then in the `multiInstanceLoopCharacteristics` you can define something like:

```
<multiInstanceLoopCharacteristics isSequential="false" flowable:collection="SOME_COLLECTION" flowable:elementVariable="SOME_ELEMENT>
    <extensionElements>
        <flowable:variableAggregation target="outputResult">
            <variable source="OUTPUT_VAR" target="OUTPUT_VAR"></variable>
        </flowable:variableAggregation>
    </extensionElements>
</multiInstanceLoopCharacteristics>
```

Doing this it will create a JSON Array result with the following structure:

```
{
    "OUTPUT_VAR": "result"
}
```